# undeclared variable. [ issue with headers ]

Tags: c, embedded

I have headers in my microcontroller program

```
 #ifndef __IRQ_HANDLER__
 #define __IRQ_HANDLER__
#ifdef __cplusplus  
volatile tU32 ticks = 0; // <- with that variable i have problem

extern "C" {
#endif
void interrupt2(void);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif


#endif //__IRQ_HANDLER__
```

Then file.c

```
#include <lpc2xxx.h>
#include "interrupt.h"

void interrupt2(void) {
    ticks++;
    T1IR = 0xff;
    VICVectAddr = 0x00;
}
```

Every time when i'm trying to use variable ticks. I got an error : 
'ticks' undeclared ( first use in this function ).

Have you any clue what might be wrong ?

Greetings !

Comment: You want the variable outside the `__cplusplus` block, otherwise it only exists in C++.

Comment: then i have the same error + "expected : "=", "," etc "

Comment: @kenik Please copy and paste your error messages in the question instead of vague approximations of them. Also post the code that they refer to.

Comment: You may also want to change the variable to an `extern volatile tU32 ticks;` And define it in **one** translation unit.

Comment: In file included from interrupt.c:2:
interrupt.h:15: error: expected `=', `,', `;', `asm' or `__attribute__' before `
ticks'
interrupt.c: In function `interrupt2':
interrupt.c:5: error: `ticks' undeclared (first use in this function)
interrupt.c:5: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
interrupt.c:5: error: for each function it appears in.)
make: *** [interrupt.o] Error 1

Comment: The second error is presumably because the compiler does not recognize `tU32` as a type.  You may need this header to include another that provides the definition of that type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: in the following code example, I stripped all the unrelated statements

1) do not declare variables in a header file.  if necessary, use the 'extern' modifier in the header file.

2) Declare the variable in a source file, like `main.c`

3)  any symbol name beginning with underscore+capital letter  Or two underscores are 'reserved' for the system.  Therefore strongly suggest replacing all instances of `__IRQ_HANDLER__`  with the (typical) `INTERRUPT_H`

an example code:

file: interrupt.h

```
#ifndef INTERRUPT_H
#define INTERRUPT_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

extern volatile unsigned int ticks;
void interrupt2(void);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif // INTERRUPT_H
```

file: interruptHandler.c

```
#include "interrupt.h"

volatile unsigned int ticks = 0;

void interrupt2(void)
{
    ticks++;
}
```

There needs to be a third file that declares the variable: `ticks`

and if declared in the file global space,
it will automatically be initialized to 0

It is necessary to also treat the code in the third file that accesses the `ticks` variable as a 'critical section.  Probably by:

1. disable the interrupts
2. copying `ticks` to a local variable
3. enable the interrupts

Comment: What should i do if i want to have access to ticks from main ?

Comment: @kenik: Include the `interrupt.h` header in the code that defines `main()`.

Comment: i put that and just got "Error 1 " :(